# How to rename shared file name using react-native-share

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having a problem on how to change the image filename when sharing via email or other platforms. I'm using `react-native-share`.

Here's my code, I followed what is written on the documentation but `filename` is not working on my end.

```
 const handleShareImage = async () => {
    try {
      const url = await captureRef(imageRef, {
        format: 'jpg',
        quality: 0.8,
        filename: 'modifiedFileName',
      });
      await Share.open({
        url: url,
        filename: 'modifiedFileName',
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  };
```

What I wanted to happen is when I click the share button, `modifiedFileName.jpg` would be the name of the file.

Comment: `filename` props in`react-native-share` only supports base64 string also only in Android : https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-open/#supported-options

Comment: I think the file is already in `base64` since I'm using this library `react-native-view-shot`. I have an option prop in my `ViewShot` which look like this. `options={{format: 'jpg', quality: 0.9, result: 'base64'}}`

Comment: Try passing `result: "data-uri"`. Also please update the question with these codes (We can't see `result` option in your question).

Comment: Passing `result: "data-uri"` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the filename in array like this in filenames parameter

```
filenames: ["YOUR_FILE_NAME.pdf"]
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work